# How to apply scss for individual pages in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm new to Blazor and I'm wondering how do you make scss file for each individual page. I know that in .NET5 you'll have scoped css but we're currently working on previous version and I want to know if it's somehow possible with scss.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Delegate.SassBuilder/ SASS compiler to achieve CSS isolation for SCSS files and this is possible only in .NET 5.0, not available in .NET 3.1. Please check this blog for more details

https://medium.com/@dharsha007/net-5-0-blazor-bites-css-isolation-for-blazor-components-part-2-fe4aa1207f2f

Regards,
Sridhar N